# material-ui card not showing on react web page

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I imported the material-ui package into my react/redux application. I am trying to display multiple search results in a card format.

I've worked with the SimpleCard sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/m5pyx6qv18) and they way I've formatted my BandResults works on the sandbox but not in my application.

Below is the BandResult js file:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import SpotifyPlayer from 'react-spotify-player'
import { SocialIcon } from 'react-social-icons'
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles'
import Card from 'material-ui/Card'
import CardContent from 'material-ui/Card'



const BandResult = props => 
        <div key={props.id}>
          <Card key={props.id}>
            <CardContent>Please Show Up</CardContent>
          </Card>
          </div>



BandResult.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    bandName: PropTypes.string,
    genre: PropTypes.string,
    numberOfMembers: PropTypes.number,
    spotify: PropTypes.string,


};





// in our Redux's state, this form will be available in 'form.login'

// Export our well formed login component
export default BandResult;
```

And here is my implementation in a map of the array of search results:

```
render() {
    const bands = this.props.resultSet

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{bands && bands.map((band) => <BandResult id={band.id} bandName={band.bandName} genre={band.genre} numberOfMembers={band.numberOfMembers} spotify={band.spotify} />)}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My console error output is:

[image: My console error output is:]

Right now, the card isn't even showing up and I cannot figure out why. When I use regular divs, ie:

```
const BandResult = props => 
        <div>
          {props.bandName}
          </div>
```

the information populates using the props.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: The code looks correct. Do you get any errors in the devtools console? And when it works with regular divs, is that when you use `bands.map((band) => <div>{band.name}</name>` ?

Comment: No I replaced Card with div. I get this error in the console as well as a few other warnings: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined
    at Card.render (Card.js:150)

Comment: The other warnings I get are:  Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.       Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: You should use `key` attribute for `card` to avoid  `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop` like `<Card key={props.id}>`

Comment: aha! so whatever x has x.muiName in the Card.js, is undefined. Could it be that you imported something like `import x from 'x'` that should instead have been `import {x} from 'x'` ? or wise versa. That would also match the second error. It's telling you that one of the elements you are rendering is not a valid. Probably it's undefined by accident

Comment: I added a key property but the error still didn't go away @Liam

Comment: @RedMercury I've changed the import statements and am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined and         Warning: Failed context type: The context `muiTheme` is marked as required in `Paper`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: These are my card import statements now:       import {Card} from 'material-ui/Card'
import {CardContent} from 'material-ui/Card'

Comment: Yes sorry, the key attribute should be for `BandResult` like `<div>{bands && bands.map((band) => <BandResult key={band.id}`

Comment: Your imports should be `import Card, { CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card'`. Card is the default export for material-ui/Card while CardContent is a named export. You can do the imports on one line.